# Clustering student based on Semantic Similarity using Hierarchical Algorithm

Tags: python, similarity, semantics

I'm quite new to the whole clustering and stuff, so I'm a bit lost in the final bit of programming. I'm working on a project which clusters students based on Semantic Similarity of topics using a Hierarchical Algorithm.

[image]

What I understand is I have to collect all topics in a list, then apply clustering techniques like Hierarchical clustering.

How can I write a code in python to cluster the students based on the semantic similarity between the topic?

Answer (score 0):

For clustering there are lot of algorithm. I propose you NLMF (Non Linear matrix factorisation), efficient and well spread. There are many others.

BASIC: If you just want to use python to achieve clustering, have a look at the python librairy nimfa: https://nimfa.biolab.si/
There are many others.
You'll have to manage you input data so they fit the expected inout format.

ADVANCED: If you want to understand, learn and maybe code an existing algorithm, look at these slides: https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/essid/teach/NMF_tutorial_ICME-2014.pdf

RESEARCH TOPIC: If you want to do your own algorithm, I can't help you in this SO answer ;)